# How can I disable To address bar for new created mail item?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I am working with Outlook addin which is perform task for creating new mail item and sent to users.
Now what I want is, I don't want to allow user to add email in To field, in short I need To field to remain disable for user, but I am not getting any way to disable it.

```
MailApp.Application oApp = new MailApp.Application();
oMailItem =(MailApp.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(MailApp.OlItemType.olMailItem);
oMailItem.To = "abc@gg.com"; // need to disable this for end user.
oMailItem.Subject = "Xyz";
oMailItem.HTMLBody = "Xyz";
oMailItem.Display(false);
```

`oMailItem.Actions[1].Enabled = false`; // it allow index from 1 to 4 which disable reply , reply all, reply to and forward option on current mail but not To field.

Please help to achieve this in my addin. How can I disable To field for end user?

Comment: u say 'I dont want to allow user to add email in TO field'. What does that mean? What is the user intended to do with the mail sent by the outlook addin? Is the user going to only edit the email body? What after that? Are u assuming that the user might accidentally starting writing the body content within TO field?

Comment: I just want to allow user to set Subject and email body in mial item. after that i will send email through code on SendEventHandler where i will populate To address as per requirement, so yes user can only edit email body and subject rest of the things will be done by code on send event

Comment: what about rewriting the TO field when mail is actually being sent?

Comment: That will be set from code before mail sent i will edit mailitem object

Answer (score 0):

The only way to disable the To field address control is to customize the form design, remove the controls and publish that form definition to that user's Personal Forms library.  For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/office/vba/outlook/concepts/forms/customizing-form-pages-and-form-regions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eric, but as i don't have much idea about outlook objects so can you please explain little bit more with piece of demo code that how can i achieve this?

Comment: Yes Eric but need some more clarification for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Eric's suggestion, you can try to hook the `MailIem.PropertyChange` event, and when (and if!) the "To" property is modified, reset it back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dmitry, but as i am new in AddIn developement so can you please advice any demo piece of code through which i can understand what i need to do is.

Comment: You need to set the oMailItem.PropertyChange event handler in your code above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to customize the built-in Outlook form and then re-publish it. It is a very old technology which is not used any longer by add-in developers.

You can use Outlook form regions and place the form to the `Replace-all` layout which replaces the whole Outlook form with the form region. Read more about that in the [Create Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2019) article on MSDN.

Also, you may consider using [Add-in Express](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-regions/form-regions.php). They provide the `CompleteReplacement` layout which also completely replace all pages of any Inspector window.

[image]

Note, in both cases, you can use any .net controls for creating a custom UI in Outlook